# Send notification to web client from external service via SignalR hub hosted in Asp.Net MVC Application

Tags: c#, architecture, signalr

Scenario is as follow : We have a Asp.Net MVC 4 App having a private messaging system that hosts a signalR hub used to notify users when new message are available for them.  Everything works fine, the Web App register connectionId along with their username and the signal is sent to the hub from the DataLayer via a notificationAdapter class.

The problem came when we had to create a separate service leveraging Quartz.Net that also send private messages when tasks are finished. We want the Quartz service to be able to contact the Hub but we can't cause it is in a separate process. I don't want to use the signalR .net client because I don't need a permanent connection between the Quartz based service and my Web App. I think of creating an endpoint in my WebSite to expose Hub's server method to the service or to use ScaleOut for that but I feel like I miss something and though I would ask the community.

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't want a permanent connection?? The whole point of the SignalR client is for out of process commincation between a hub. You could do what you suggested, but it kind of defeats the whole purpose of SignalR and you would lose out on any kind of bi-directional communication...

Comment: @Steve :I guess I don't want it because I don't need it to be permanent nor bi directional.

Comment: Have you considered using a Bus (RabbitMQ, NServiceBus, etc)?  Quartz.Net can publish a message on the Bus and a subscriber would pick up the message and send an alert to any connected clients (Web app) via SignalR.

Comment: @dpwilson That's the best option until now so both services stayed decoupled but it feels like a canon to beat a fly isn't it ?

Comment: @VdesmedT I agree that adding a service bus layer is a bit of overkill if you are not using it elsewhere in your system.  I have used a Bus in the exact situation that you are describing (even used Quartz.net), but I was already using the Bus in my application so it was a fairly painless implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be a very late answer but seeing as there were no actual accepted answer. I'll provide one.

The easiest way to have your Quartz.NET application send information to your ASP.NET Web Application without implementing a heavy solution such as Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) is to simply expose a web service in ASP.NET and have your Quartz.NET call the ASP.NET web service when its task is finished. Once you're in your ASP.NET web service you should be able to a notification back to send a notification to the client through signalR.

Comment: That is indeed what I did at the time ;-) Thank you

Comment: @VdesmedT I'm having the same problem right now. How did you restrict access to the endpoint your Quartz.NET application used to push the message? How did you make sure, that no other user but only the quartz service could call this endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I would have used Quartz Listener (Job or trigger listener) in the WebAPI, which then talks to the Hub.

Of course, use a shared ADO store between Quartz client (web API) and server (windows service).